# Windows Service Structure

Tags: c#, windows, service

My issue is that I have a windows service that is running my onstart code as soon as I start the service and then again after the one minute timer I have set initiates it. If anyone has an idea of what would cause this that would be great. If not an explanation of how the windows service structure would be helpful. Below I have copied a service outline; I am most curious as to what can and should go  in the class before the constructor and in the constructor. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
namespace TestService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {   
        //What can/should go in here : When will this execute

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What timer? There's none in your code...

Comment: I don't have the real program I'm working on to post but it has a timer declared in the portion above the constructor above. So I guess it would be a global declaration in the class.

Comment: If you declare a timer it will call the timer function every `TimeInterval`.
Your `OnStart()` function is called when the service starts. What is the problem?